# Ad Mob on Android Problems

Tags: android, admob

I tried to ad admob to my app but it would not request anything from the site. I followed all of the directions but in the logs I could see that a request went to api.admob.com but that was the end of it. It seems as if nothing was returned. I tried test mode and regular mode and got the same results with both.

I guess my question is, is there anything missing from the Admob docs or should it work if I follow the directions exactly?

Comment: You're lucky, admob will not yield you a significant profit, and will simply depreciate the value of your app significantly.

Figure out a better business model.

Comment: Yea, I just ended up making it a paid app. I was really more interested in figuring out how to make it work than making money with it.

Comment: Maybe we can help you if you could post the code with your admob integration.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue at first. Problem was solved by logging into my admob account and changing the interval at which the ad's are refreshed. Once i did this everything started working fine... Not sure what the hiccup was.